# During what hours does the Chinese consulate in Mexico City accept visa applications?

Tags: visas, china, consulates, opening-hours, mexico-city

I want to apply for a Chinese visa in the coming days here in Mexico City.

I'm having some difficulty finding the times during which the consulate is open for visa applications.

I know from previous experience that it is often just a couple of hours per day in the morning before lunch.

Can somebody point to the time for this particular consulate?

Comment: That's pretty generous if they accept visa applications for that entire time. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've now been to the Chinese consulate in Mexico City twice.

There is no separate timetable for when the consulate accepts visa applications in comparison to its opening hours generally.

So you can lodge a visa application during the whole 4-hour period from 9am to 1pm.

In practice I find the office may close 10 minutes or so early. My passport photo issued in the immigration office in Guangzhou for a visa extension was not acceptable for applying for a Chinese visa in Mexico City. I got back from the photo shop about ten minutes before 1pm but the doors were now close.